# Decimal separator comma but I want save data with point

Tags: c#, excel

I have to read and write an excel file.
The problem is that when a PC is the decimal separator, (comma) also in the excel file numbers with the comma will be saved.
I would like to save the values for all modes with the point instead of a comma.

Here is a piece of code:

```
var wb = openWorkBook(filename);
var ws = wb.Worksheet("CNF");
IXLRow row = ws.Row(device.Ordinal - 1 + FirstRow);
for (int j = 0; j < MAXCOLS; ++j)
{
   IXLCell cell = row.Cell(j + FirstCol);

   cell.Value = Convert.ChangeType(device[j], m_column_type[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) uses the thread's current culture for conversion. It sounds like you want the invariant culture, so you should use [`Convert.ChangeType(object, Type, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
cell.Value = Convert.ChangeType(device[j], m_column_type[j], 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @fede186: Well yes, you *could* do that, but it's not the best solution. It's better to avoid the comma existing to start with.

Comment: Because I saw that in the beginning there are only points in the file is read and then when the data is inserted into some textbox is read as points if the decimal separator is the point, as a comma if there is a comma in decimal.
In case you want to change the value in the textbox if there is a comma in decimal not allow me even to insert a point and then the end will save me the comma in the whole line of corrispoindente excel file.

Comment: I know that was not very smart on the replace but perhaps to avoid putting your hands in many parts of code I thought you could do a replace commas with points only where the lines of the excel file are saved.

Comment: @fede186: Sorry, I didn't really understand all of that comment, but basically you should be very clear about the difference between textual data which needs parsing, and the end result of the parsing - I read your question as a situation where you already have the parsed data and you're trying to convert it into a textual form, but using `.` as the decimal separator. That's what my answer addresses. If that's not the case, you should edit your question to be clearer. (It doesn't help that we have no idea what's in `device` or `m_column_type`. A [mcve] would really help.)